# Ruby's self vs. Python's self

Tags: python, ruby, keyword, self

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Ruby and Python versions of“self”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159990/what-is-the-difference-between-ruby-and-python-versions-ofself)

Ruby and Python are similar languages that both have a `self` keyword used in various situations. What does `self` mean in each language, and what are the differences?

Comment: Python doesn't have a `self` keyword. It's only used by convention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding Python I can tell you nothing new. The `self` there is passed conventionally as the first parameter of a method, as pst said. From [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

> Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that relies upon such a convention.

CRuby (or 'MRI') has something similar which happens under the hood though. Every C extension may define (module/class/singleton) methods on a Ruby class by using

- rb_define_method (instance)
- rb_define_singleton_method (singleton class)
- rb_define_module_function (class/module)

The actual implementing functions always take `VALUE self` as their first argument, in analogy to the Python idiom. `self` in these cases refers to the object instance this particular message has been sent to, i.e. if you have

```
 person = Person.new
 person.do_sth
```

and do_sth would happen to be implemented in C, then there would be a corresponding C function

```
VALUE
person_do_sth(VALUE self) {
    //do something
    return self;
}
```

Every such implementation *has* to return a `VALUE` (the C representation of a Ruby object), which relates to the fact that every method call or *message sent* (to stick to Smalltalk parlance) has a return value in Ruby. There is no such thing as a `void` function in Ruby.

Although we need to pass `self` back and forth in the low-level C code, you don't need to do so in Ruby code, Ruby takes care of this for you. The current value of self is stored internally in the current thread context that is executed, so the existence of `self` is granted, the message "self" will always evaluate to some object.

Due to the dynamic nature of Ruby, the actual value of of this object being referenced by `self` changes with the current scope of the code that is currently interpreted. Run this to see for yourself:

```
puts "#{self} - declared in global scope"  # the 'top self' aka 'main'
class << self
  puts "#{self} - 'main's singleton class" # main's singleton or 'eigenclass'
end

puts "Starting to interpret class A code"

class A
  puts "#{self} - When do I get executed!?" # self is class A

  class << self
    puts "#{self} - And me!?" # now A's  singleton class
    def a # declaring method in class's singleton class results in class method
      puts "#{self} - declared in singleton class" # it's A
    end 
  end

  def self.b
    puts "#{self} - declared in class method" # self is class A again -> class method
    class << self
      puts "#{self} - declared in Class A's singleton class" # now it's Class A's singleton class
    end
  end

  def c
    puts "#{self} - declared in instance method" # self is instance of A
    class << self
      puts "#{self} - declared in instance's singleton class" # now it's the A instance's singleton class
    end
  end

end  

puts "All so far has happened simply by interpreting A's code" 

a = A.new
A.a
A.b
a.c
```

If you want to call a method/send a message from any context to `self`, you could do this either explicitly (e.g. `self.method`) or you omit `self` as the receiver - then, by convention, the implicit receiver of the message will be `self`.

An interesting side note to this is Ruby's interpretation of `private` methods, which differs e.g. from the Java notion of `private`. Ruby's private methods are only callable by sending a message using `self` as an implicit receiver, i.e.

```
class A

  def a
    b
  end

  private

  def b
    puts "I'm private"
  end
end

a = A.new
a.a # => I'm private
```

works, whereas replacing method a by

```
def a
  self.b
end
```

would raise an exception. This implies that something very common in Java

```
class A {
    private boolean compareUs(A a1, A a2) { ... }

    public boolean equals(A a1, A a2) {
        return (a1.compareUs() == a2.compareUs());
    }
}
```

won't work in Ruby. Silly example, but just to illustrate the point: In Java we can access private methods of other instances of the same class, this would not be possible in Ruby because we can only access private methods of the current `self`.

Finally, to complicate things a bit further, the `instance_eval` and `class_eval` functions will also alter the value of `self` during execution.

Comment: "return (a1.compareUs() == a2.compareUs())" really? the compareUs() method need 2 parameters

Answer (score 14):

Ruby and Python are actually *very different languages* (although they do share many similarities) even if Ruby has a syntax that can be written to look like Python (with the inclusion of `end` keywords) ;-)

Ruby is message-based (it was heavily influenced by SmallTalk-80) and "messages" are sent to objects. Ruby supports an *implicit* receiver (explicitly known as `self`) for a given scope. In Ruby `self` *is not a variable*, but rather an expression that evaluates to the current object context.

Python is property-based (for lack of a better term I know) and is thus more similar to SELF and JavaScript as functions are executed directly (instead of messages being passed). Python has no `self` keyword and it is merely convention that `self` is used as *the name of the first parameter of a method* -- which is how Python passes around the current object context.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 9):

In Python, `my_instance.a_method(an_argument)` is just shorthand for `MyClass.a_method(my_instance, an_argument)`.  Thus the definition of `MyClass.a_method` should take two parameters:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def a_method(self, an_argument):
        print self   # self (the instance) is available in the method
```

As pst said, the use of the variable name `self` is just a convention.  You could equally have

```
class MyClass(object):
    def a_method(this_instance, an_argument):
        print this_instance
```

and everything would work the same...but don't do that.